# wxDataViewListCtrl change cell background color

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

As the title, is possible to change the background color of a single cell in a wxDataViewListCtrl? If not, is possible to change the background color of an entire row?
How can I do it? Others solutions?
Thanks a lot in advance for some advice

Answer (score 2):

For those who might be interested I have solved as follows

1. Extend wxDataViewCustomRenderer

> ```
> class MyColorRenderer: public wxDataViewCustomRenderer
> {
> public:
>     explicit MyColorRenderer(wxDataViewCellMode mode) : wxDataViewCustomRenderer("string", mode, wxALIGN_CENTER)
>     { 
>   }
>     virtual bool Render( wxRect rect, wxDC *dc, int state ) override;
>
>     virtual bool ActivateCell(const wxRect& WXUNUSED(cell), wxDataViewModel*WXUNUSED(model), const wxDataViewItem &WXUNUSED(item), unsigned int WXUNUSED(col), const wxMouseEvent *mouseEvent) override
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
>     virtual wxSize GetSize() const override
>     {
>         return wxSize(60,20);
>     }
>
>     virtual bool SetValue( const wxVariant &value ) override
>     {
>         m_value = value.GetString();
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     virtual bool GetValue( wxVariant &WXUNUSED(value) ) const override { return true; }
>     virtual bool HasEditorCtrl() const override { return true; }
>
>     virtual wxWindow*
>     CreateEditorCtrl(wxWindow* parent, wxRect labelRect,  const wxVariant& value) override
>     {
>         wxTextCtrl* text = new wxTextCtrl(parent, wxID_ANY, value, labelRect.GetPosition(), labelRect.GetSize(), wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER);
>         text->SetInsertionPointEnd();
>
>         return text;
>     }
>     virtual bool
>     GetValueFromEditorCtrl(wxWindow* ctrl, wxVariant& value) override
>     {
>         wxTextCtrl* text = wxDynamicCast(ctrl, wxTextCtrl);
>         if ( !text )
>             return false;
>
>         value = text->GetValue();
>
>         return true;
>     }
> private:
>     wxString m_value;
> };
> ```

2. Override render method

> ```
>  bool MyColorRenderer::Render( wxRect rect, wxDC *dc, int state )
>     {
>         dc->SetBrush( wxColour(m_value) );
>         rect.Deflate(2);
>         dc->DrawRoundedRectangle( rect, 5 );
>         return true;
>    }
> ```

3. create the cell as needed

> lst->AppendColumn(new wxDataViewColumn("Colore",new
> MyColorRenderer(wxDATAVIEW_CELL_INERT),5, 60, wxALIGN_CENTER));

Answer (score 1):

You can override `wxDataViewListModel::GetAttrByRow()` in your custom model to return the attributes with the colours (and fonts etc) you want for any cell.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try this way. I have to search about and I'll put here the code If I have problem